# How to reduce the borders around subplots in matlab AND subaxis doesn't work

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I've written a GUI that gives a matlab subplot of varying size and I'm looking for a generic way to squeeze the subplots together. Subaxis works for the vertical spacing, but it doesn't affect the horizontal spacing.

What's the simplest way to squeeze them together?
[An example of one of the output figures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdLXI.jpg) it was produced with the following code in a for loop

```
 subaxis (1+ceil(max(zindex)/5),5,5+i, 'Padding', 0, 'Margin', 0,'SpacingHoriz',0.0001,'SpacingVert',0.009);
```

Comment: Can you show how you call subaxis? It should work in a similar way for horizontal and vertical 'squeezing'.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin in a loop subaxis(1+ceil(max(zindex)/5),5,5+i, 'Padding', 0, 'Margin', 0,'SpacingHoriz', 0.0001,'SpacingVert',0.009);%shape of plot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your figure dimensions are way different than the number of plots you have.  Subaxis works best if you define your figure size, and you should pick the aspect ratio based on how many plots you have.

in the example you have 13 x 5 subplots, but your figure's aspect ratio is more like 7:13.  Hence the vertical plots are close together but there is much horizontal white space.

Before plotting, try defining your figure like:

```
nRows=13;
nCols=5;
PlotWidth=3;  %This is your Plot width in cm. 
FigW=nCols*FigWidth;
FigH=nRows*FigWidth;   %Note: I'm assuming the plots are square
Figure1=figure(1);clf;
set(Figure1,'PaperUnits','centimeters',...
      'PaperSize',[FigW FigH],...
      'PaperPosition',[0,0,FigW,FigH],...
      'Units','centimeters','Position',[1,9,FigW,FigH]);
```

and see if your figure spacing looks better.  A few notes, if you want to use 'inches' instead of cm that's fine.  Also, I don't have any margins on my paper plot (defining the paper-size and paper position is useful for exporting).  If you wanted a margin you might try something like:

```
Mgn=1;
set(Figure1,'PaperUnits','centimeters',...
      'PaperSize',[FigW+2*Mgn FigH+2*Mgn],...
      'PaperPosition',[Mgn,Mgn,FigW,FigH],...
      'Units','centimeters','Position',[1,9,FigW,FigH]);
```

You can then export using matlab's [print](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html) command to the format of your choice.