# MATLAB Create Movie

Tags: matlab, movie

** I figured out how to create the movie so the code has been changed to reflect the correct one in case it is useful for anyone in the future. 
This script creates a movie of a eqdconic map and saves it in avi format. The movie will run through 1255 frames. It also plots a dot at a certain point on the image, places a changing title on the movie to show what month is being run through, and has a colorbar on the right side.

Some of the variables used were created elsewhere. The code for creating them has been left out to condense the code (and since they will not be useful for anyone else other than myself).

```
% Create movie
    nFrames = 34; % Number of frames

for k = 1:nFrames
    % Eqdconic script    
    % Define figure and axes
    fg1 = figure(1);
    axesm('MapProjection','eqdconic', 'MapParallels', [], 'MapLatLimit',[-80 -59],'MapLonLimit',[190 251]) % 60-70S and 120-160W
    framem on; gridm on; mlabel on; plabel on; hold all;

    % Plot data
    frame = dataPoint_movie(:,:,k);
    image = contourfm(lat,lon,frame, 'LineStyle', 'none');

    hold on

    % Plot dot    
    plotm(-66.75,224,'k.','MarkerSize',30); 

    % Colorbar
    caxis([0 100]); 
    h = colorbar;
    ylabel(h,'Percent');

    % Title: Days 1:1258 inclusive. 20100101 to 20130611
    date = datenum(2009, 12, 31) + k; % Convert t into serial numbers
    str = datestr(date, 'mmm yyyy'); % Show in the format mmm yyyy so title changes only once a month
    title(str);

    mov(k) = getframe(gcf); % gca would give only the image. gcf places the title and other attributes on the movie.
end

close(gcf)

% % Save as AVI file 
movie2avi(mov, 'SeaIceConcentration.avi', 'compression', 'none', 'fps', 2);
```

Comment: does the `for t = 1:12`-loop generate a plot or also just empty axis?

Comment: Based on the [`getframe`-documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html), have you tried `A(i)` instead of `A(:,:,i)`?

Comment: Why do you loop from `i=1:numframes` and then for each `i` again from `t=1:1258`?

Comment: Just tried A(i). Still a blank plot. I've tested the contourfm plot section for 1 image at a time, and that works. So I believe it's the movie that doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you need the `t`-loop? If I understand you correctly, your `numframes` is equal to the number of days.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. But now, I have an image up. But it doesn't seem to be playing. Do you think the speed is wrong? Or maybe it's just not working.

Comment: Read [the documentation on `movie`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movie.html) - the speed in frames-per-second is the third input. The second input is the number of repeats.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to export my movies from matlab to a .avi file.

before the for loop, initialize your movie:

```
vidObj = VideoWriter('Movie.avi');
vidObj.FrameRate=23;
open(vidObj);
```

then get your frame in the for loop:

```
A = getframe;
writeVideo(vidObj,A);
```

(note, i'm not saving each frame in a matrix, so A is an MxN matrix)

Then write out your movie after the for loop

```
 close(vidObj);
```

The movie will be in your current working directory.  you can open using quicktime or some other avi player.  To change the frame rate (speed) of your movie, edit the second line of code.  23 fps is a good smooth movie framerate.

Comment: I don't mean to be snarky, but these are really separate questions, and the purpose of these forums is not to debug your specific code.  

For the date, try looking at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16502693/date-from-multiple-strings-in-matlab).

For the figure resize, you can do so with the set command, as  [illustrated here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478132/how-to-reduce-the-borders-around-subplots-in-matlab-and-subaxis-doesnt-work/16922127#16922127).

Answer (score 1):

Check the consistency of the statements:

```
A = dataPoint(:,:,t);
```

and

```
A(i) = getframe;
```

A is overwritten all the time So that you will at best get the last frame.